# Call GoogleAds report API from REST/SOAP Client

Tags: python, rest, api, google-ads-api

- I have googleads AUDIENCE_PERFORMANCE_REPORT in my Ads i can access
  this report using the AWQL which is fine but now i have requirement
  to get this report data using the API call instead of AWQL
- I have tried to explore SOAP and REST end point for googleadd reports
  where i am able to send payload for getting data from report Here's

[Addwords API]https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/call-structure

```
import sys
import datetime
from googleads import adwords
from datetime import date, datetime, timedelta
from pprint import pprint
import argparse
import random
import time
MAX_RETRY_ATTEMPTS = 10

### Google Adwords API call
def main(client, g_date, acnt_id):

  # print g_date

  # Initialize appropriate service.
  report_downloader = client.GetReportDownloader(version='v201809')

  # Create report query.
  report_query = (adwords.ReportQueryBuilder()
                  .Select('Date', 'AccountDescriptiveName', 'CampaignId','CampaignName', 'UserListName', 'Criteria',
                          'Status', 'Clicks', 'Impressions', 'Cost','Conversions')
                  .From('AUDIENCE_PERFORMANCE_REPORT')
                  #.Where('Status').In('ENABLED', 'PAUSED','REMOVED') #.During('20180901,20180901')
                  .During(start_date=g_date,end_date=g_date)
                  .Build())
  print(report_downloader)
  print("====================")
  print(report_query)
```

1. Using the above code i can able to download report. I ran program and try to use fiddler trace to get HTTPS calls from but no luck in that.
2. My requirement is to either create this report and then pull reports
   data 
       using the REST/SOAP based API.
3. I am not able to find any relevant information on this any help is
   appreciate.

Comment: `googleads` module wraps the Adwords API endpoint https://adwords.google.com/api/adwords/cm/v201809 so you're actually working with SOAP-based API. Could you please clarify what you're trying to achieve?
There's also JSON based API called Google Ads API but it's turn to beta recently so I'm not sure you can use it. Here's a report exampe from Ads API docs https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/reporting/example

Comment: Thanks for update i am trying to pull report data between two dates and download report data in CSV or get data as json or xml i am fine xml or JSON.